# Python: How to print the value of variable in color

Tags: python, escaping

I am aware of printing the statements in color. Eg:

"\033[34mHow are you ? \033[0m" -> This will print the statement in blue color.

But what if the string is stored in a variable, and then I need to print the value of the variable in color.

string= "How are you?"

print string

In the above case, I need when the value of string is printed, the output is in blue color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python gives a variety of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just concat the colour sections of the String together when printing your string like so:

```
string = "How are you?" 
print "\033[34m" + string + "\033[0m"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use formated strings (old-style) like:

```
colors = {'reset':'\033[0m', 'blue':'\033[34m'}
person = 'you'
formattext = 'How are %s%s%s' %(colors['blue'], person, colors['reset'])
```

%s defines a string place-holder see: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

btw: [Stack overflow on python string formating](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20string%20formating)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("")
message='How are you?'
print('\033[0;32m'+message+'\033[0m')
```

Output:

**How are you?**  (it will be print in green color)

For the color code reference please check: https://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

Comment: But this answer essentially reiterates what has already been said (not to mention the `os.system()` step seems rather arbitrary.